# Error: option clash for package hyperref

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I downloaded this master thesis format from the net, It was compiling without errors until I added this line `\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}`because I want to show the bookmarks table in the PDF file. And here is the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} 

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} 
\title{\ttitle}
```

Please, could anyone help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: presumably your local thesis class has already loaded hyperref try `\hypersetup{bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2}` instead

Comment: [Welcome!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Learn how to ask a question: `caption.sty` seems irrelevant? Don't mention it except if someone ask a question about it. Please provide a link to the "master thesis from the net".

Comment: Here is the link that you requested for the master thesis http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/

Answer (score 7):

Presumably your local thesis class has already loaded hyperref try

```
\hypersetup{bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2}
```

instead.